# lookup stage in datastage 8.5 with multiple rows returned from link

Tags: datastage

I am trying to pull XML data from Lookup stage. I have multiple key values coming from the reference table. I selected the link name from the Multiple rows returned from link drop-down list. I am getting the output in two different blocks.

Ex:

```
Purchase order: 2141340 Type code: A
Purchase order: 2141340 Type Code:B
```

I need the both type code should come in the single block as like below:

*Expected Output:*

```
PurchaseOrder Number="2141340"
BookingId 1 BookingId
TypeCode A TypeCode
TypeCode B TypeCode
/purchaseOrder
```

*Actual output:*

```
PurchaseOrder Number="2141340"
BookingId 1 BookingId
TypeCode A TypeCode
/purchaseOrder

PurchaseOrder Number="2141340"
BookingId 1 BookingId
TypeCode B TypeCode
/purchaseOrder
```

Anyone can help me on this?